# Lower bound an expression given a relationship between three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

Given the following relationship between three variables $$ |x|^2 \leq 2|y|^2 \leq |z|^2$$

I would like to lower bound the function $F$ below and end up with function of $z$ only.

I think this can be justified as

$$ F=\big| |x| - y \big|^2 \stackrel{(a)}{\geq} \big| |x| - |y| \big|^2 = \big(|x| - |y| \big)^2\geq f(z)$$

Can anyone find what $f(z)$ is?

What if the condition was 
$$   2|y|^2 \leq |z|^2\leq |x|^2$$

Can I say the following 
$$\big| |x| - y \big|^2 {\geq}\big| |x| - |y| \big|^2 =  \big( |x| - |y| \big)^2\geq  (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2|x|^2$$
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality does not hold. For instance, take $x=y=1$ and $z \geq \sqrt{2}.$

Steps $(a)$  and $(b)$ are correct. One problem is in

$$\big| |x| - |y| \big|^2 \geq \big| |x| - \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{2}} \big|^2, $$

which is not true. Actually, we can easily find $x, y,z$ such that $|x|$ is closer to $|y|$ than $\frac{|z|}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Another problem is in the step

$$\big|  \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{2}}- |x| \big|^2\geq \big|  \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{2}}- |z| \big|^2.$$

Notice that $x=1$ and $z = \sqrt{2}$ gives a counterexample.

**UPDATE:**

The inequality  $\big| |x| - |y| \big|^2 \geq  \big( |x| - |y| \big)^2$ is actually an equality, because $|a|^2=a^2.$

Otherwise, your inequality holds. Notice that

$$ \big( |x| - |y| \big)^2 =  \left(1 - \frac{|y|}{|x|}\right)^2 |x|^2 \geq (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2|x|^2,$$ because $\frac{|y|}{|x|} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$

**UPDATE 2:**

$f(z) = 0$ is a lowerbound for $\big(|x| - |y| \big)^2$.

**UPDATE 3:**

You cannot find a lowerbound  $f(z) \neq 0$. Notice that the lowerbound must be satisfied for  all $x$ and $y$. So, for $x=y=0$, zero is the only lowerbound $ \left (\text{I've assumed} \hspace{1mm}f(z) \geq 0 \right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have added a second part to this question can you please check?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo ai mean to compare in the second part of the question $$ \big( |x| - |y| \big)^2\geq  (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2|x|^2,$$

Comment: I think know they are equal with your numerical example

Comment: @Henry, I have fixed now.

Comment: thank you Alex I thought u deleted your answer, I was wondering regarding my first relationship the one you verified was wrong, do you think there is any way, where I lower bound in the end with a function of $z$ only?

Comment: so the function $f(z) \neq 0$ can't be found?

Comment: i need it to be a function of $z$, I didnt know you would give an answer $f(z)=0$..,

Comment: @Henry, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look correct step (a) can be verified maybe by triangle inequality..